# How to confront lengths of every row of a specific column in a table to a specific value from a support table and create a Flag when condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, for-loop

I have loaded a table as a dataframe in Python and I want to check if the length of all the variables respect the length indicated for each variable in a supporting table.

The table (Table 1) I have loaded is structured like this
 [Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPRou.png)

and the table (Table 2) indicating how long the variable should be is the following:
[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cT1B7.png)

I would like to confront the length of every row for each column in Table 1 for the length in Table 2 and create a Flag, so that when the condition on that row is not met I get 1, otherwise 0

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5fCf.png)

I'm not an expert, so I've tried the following code:

```py
new = pd.Dataframe()
for c,f in zip(Table2['variable'],Table2['length']):
    if f == Table1[c].astype(str).str.len():
        new['warning_'+c] == 0
    else:
        new['warning_'+c] == 1
```

I get the following error:
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
s = Table2.set_index('variable')['length']
Table1 = Table1.applymap(len).ne(s).astype(int).add_prefix('check_')
```

Alternative:

```
Table1 = Table1.apply(lambda x: x.str.len()).ne(s).astype(int).add_prefix('check_')

print (Table1)
   check_A  check_B  check_C
0        1        0        0
1        0        0        1
2        0        1        1
```

Explanation:

First get length of strings for all values with [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) or [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with [`Series.str.len`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.len.html):

```
print (Table1.applymap(len))

   A  B  C
0  5  2  7
1  4  2  2
2  4  5  2
```

Then convert `Table2` to `Series` with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
s = Table2.set_index('variable')['length']
print (s)
variable
A    4
B    2
C    7
Name: length, dtype: int64
```

And compare by not equal by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html), then convert to integers for `True/False` to `1/0` mapping:

```
print (Table1.applymap(len).ne(s).astype(int))
   A  B  C
0  1  0  0
1  0  0  1
2  0  1  1
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked great!
What if I want to modify the Check Flag and put a condition for 1 only if the length of the variable is greater than what value is indicated in Table 2?
Anyway, thank you again for the great explanation!

Comment: @inegue - then use `gt` for `>`, or `ge` for `>=` or `eq` for `==`

Comment: Thank you! Any idea on how to treat missing values? I would like to read NA as 0 in length

Comment: @inegue use `print (Table1.applymap(len).notna().astype(int))`